Movie like the song hotel california
This movie, I can't seem to find. I've been looking for years. I'm guessing it came out sometime after 2000.
The plot is something like the song hotel California. Though it's four friends driving somewhere and they come into fog for a while. When it sort of clears there's a motel or bed and breakfast. The other guests keep disappearing and the keepers of the place seem shady. Then there's something about the wine they serve so it makes the guests think its the same day over and over. 
I can't remember how it ends or the name of the movie, it's been bugging me for so long!

Very possibly Portal from 2009. It only has 2 protagonists, but there are other people stuck in there as well and trying to get out:

Portal starts as two musicians make their way to a gig, Hooke (Chris Condrad) & His mate Gibbs (Alexander Martin) have been driving for hours in a thick fog that seems never ending when they are nearly run off the road by a truck. Stopping & getting out the friends decide to head to a nearby motel to spend the night & wait for the dense fog to burn away, the motel has a creepy owner named Benedict (Kevin Dobson) & the other guest's seem sort of weird too. Hookes decides not to eat the meat & veg [& wine] which turns out to be a good move since it's full of mind altering ash that makes you forget that you have been stuck in the same motel for months repeating the same thing over & over again.

Here's the trailer:



